# Performance problems finding dots on mouseover

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Well I am trying to make an animation where there are a lot of dots on the canvas and on mouseover they are hidden and after a timeout shown again.
The mouseover effect shouldn't just happen on the exact spot the mouse is but in e.g. a box of 20x20 pixels.

In my prototype I have these loops...

```
for (var i = -10; i <= 10; i++) {
  for (var j = -10; j <= 10; j++) {
            var imagedata = c.getImageData(x+i, y+j, 1, 1).data;
    if (imagedata[0] == 99) {
      fadeInRectangle(c, x+i,y+j);
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a quicker way to find dots where the mouse is? It doesn't have to be a square it can be a circle also where the position is checked... I don't care. Thanks in advance

The fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vrjw996h/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is create an array of dot objects, each one storing the dot's `x` and `y` position, as well as a `visible` property (Like `{x:10, y: 40, visible: true}`). Whenever the mouse moves, loop through each object and check the distance between the mouse and the dot. If a dot is found to be in range, set its property `visible` to `false`. After that part, still inside `onmousemove`, clear the canvas and redraw each dot, skipping those with `visible: false`. After a few seconds, set `visible` back to `true`.

https://jsfiddle.net/Howzieky/vrjw996h/1/